# Online judge Rejecting My Answer

Tags: c++, long-integer, palindrome

The Next Palindrome

The below code is the solution to this problem

A positive integer is called a palindrome if its representation in the decimal system is the same when read from left to right and from right to left. For a given positive integer K of not more than 1000000 digits, write the value of the smallest palindrome larger than K to output. Numbers are always displayed without leading zeros.

**Input**

The first line contains integer t, the number of test cases. Integers K are given in the next t lines.

**Output**

For each K, output the smallest palindrome larger than K.

**Example**

**Input:**
2
808
2133

**Output:**
818
2222

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
 long t;
 cin>>t;
 long a[t],k;
 for(long i=0;i<t;++i)
{

    cin>>k;
    a[i]=k;

}

 for(long i=0;i<t;++i)
 {
    long palin=0,num;
    palin=a[i];
    num=palin+1;

    while(1)
    {
        long x=0,rev=0,ans=num;
        do
        {
            x=ans%10;
            rev=rev*10+x;
            ans=ans/10;
        }while(ans);  
        if(rev==num)
        {
            cout<<"\n"<<rev<<"\n";
            break;
        }    
        else
            ++num;
    }     
 }      
return 0;
}
```

The code is giving me expected output, I even made changes in the code making the variable K and t to LONG, should i make them long long instead of long, or is there any issue with my logic ...?

Comment: If the given number has up to 1000000 digits, you can't use normal integer types (even `long long`). You can treat the number as a string and handle each digit separately.

Comment: One million decimal digits is over 3 million bits.

Comment: Though your needs here are simple enough that you don't actually need to do much in the way of *math* on your large numbers, a topic for you to read about: [Arbitrary-Precision ("BigNum") arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a effective program by using a string instead of long. I have used it. Here I am giving the code:

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

#include<string.h>

int main()
{
    char s[80];   //you can take any big index instead 80
    gets(s);
    int a=0,l=strlen(s);

    for(int i=0;i<l;i++) {
        if(s[i]==s[l-i]) {
            a++;
        }
    }

    if(a==l) {
        cout<<"Number is palindrome";
    }
    else {
        cout<<"Number is not palindrome";
    }

    return(0);
}
```

Comment: One of the benefits of using C++ is not needing to use fixed-size buffers.  Please read [Learning Standard C++ as a New Language](http://www.stroustrup.com/new_learning.pdf) to get the gist of what the difference is all about.  You shouldn't need to use `strlen` or `#include <string.h>` in a C++ program.

Comment: @niru Thanks u really made the program so small and simple :)

Answer (score 2):

Is the task really to handle integers up to 1,000,000 digits? Or is the input smaller than 1M? 
"long" is guaranteed to be at least 32 bits long (so an unsigned long can hold integers [0, 4,294,967,295]. So if your input is < 1M, your safe with just regular long.
"long long" is guaranteed to be at least 64 bits long, so the range for unsigned long long is [0, 18x10^18]. Larger than 4M but still much smaller than 1M decimal digits.

Another issue with your code is the fact that it looks like your trying to dynamically allocate a stack array.

```
cin>>t;
long a[t],k;
```

You can't provide a variable as the array size. This is a very basic point an C++, and you must do one of the following:

1. Use a constant compile-time maximum size for the array (simplest solution).

   ```
   #define A_MAX_SIZE 100
   long a[A_MAX_SIZE];
   ```
2. Use a dynamic array (but then you must allocated and delete it later).
   See link: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/dynamic/
3. Use an STL container that will take care of memory for you.
   For example: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/vector/

Comment: *You can't provide a variable as the array size.*; as a point of curiosity, C99--however unwise it may be--has [Variable Length Arrays](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array).  The reasons for rejecting including them in C++ are worth understanding.